# How to add timestamp to bash after completed command

Tags: bash

I would like to add the current time upon execution of a bash command. I would like it to be in the right hand site so not to be intrusive. The output I am looking for is:

```
batman@Batcave:~/grails$ ls -l
total 84
drwxr-xr-x 2 batman batman  4096 2011-02-16 09:54 bin
drwxr-xr-x 2 batman batman  4096 2011-02-16 08:24 scripts
drwxr-xr-x 9 batman batman  4096 2011-02-16 08:24 src
batman@Batcave:~/grails$                                                       **10:46:06**
```

ideas on how to accomplish this??

Comment: What's the aim here? Just to show the current time or to show the time that something completed?

Comment: show the the time the last command was completed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something similar, but not exactly, what you ask: add the following lines to your `~/.bashrc`

```
mytime() {
    printf '%*s**%s**\n' $((COLUMNS-13)) "" "$(date +%T)"
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=mytime
```

The difference is that the time is shown on the previous line, not the current.
I think it should be difficult to write on the current line without interfering with the shell prompt and line editing.

Comment: can you make it on the same line as the command was issued?

Comment: @Pomario: as I already said, I think it is difficult, which implicitly means that I don't know how.

Comment: you can just use a carriage return instead of a newline in the printf command: `mytime() { printf "%*s\r" $(tput cols) "$(date '+**%T**')"; }`

Comment: @glennjackman: yeah, I tried this, and it doesn't work before. In any case, it get deleted as soon as you use the Backspace to delete a char.

Comment: Hmm, works for me. What's your `$TERM`? I have vt100 and xterm on a couple of machines.

Comment: @glennjackman: same behavior in with `TERM=screen`, `xterm` and `linux`.

Comment: @glennjackman: You should enter that as an answer. It works fine for me. I'd like to upvote it and give you some rep. :) I've added it to my `.bashrc`.